# Jquery input ID from Class

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<div class="buttons">   

<input id = "previous" class="previous_button" type="submit" 
style="margin-right: 10px;" value="Previous"/>

<input id = "next" class="next_button" type="submit" 
style="margin-right: 10px;" value="Next"/>

</div>
```

How can I get the id of the clicked button when I have the following code:

```
$(".buttons").click(function(){
        //alert("Clicked!");
        //alert($('.buttons').closest('form').attr('id'));


     })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event delegation

```
$('.buttons').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```